# Circuit not working: Differential impedance, or skew, or a different problem responsible?

Tags: lvds, skew

For a hobby project, I am designing a circuit that converts displayport to APIX2, which is a serializer protocol used in cars' infotainment systems, mostly BMW. This is done by an INAP375T IC, APIX is basically LVDS.

I am using a FR4 four layer pcb, which according to the manufacturer constists of:

```
layer1     35µm copper
separator1 181µm
separator2 181µm
layer2     35µm copper
separator3 710µm
layer3     35µm copper
separator4 181µm
separator5 181µm
layer4     35µm copper
```

I don't know what the inner layers are called, I used the term separator; total thickness is 1.6mm. My traces are 0.3mm wide and 0.3mm apart, which results in 109 ohm Z_diff and 70 ohm Z_o, according to saturn pcb toolkit, when using layer2 as ground layer.

The manufacturer of the APIX2 ICs (INAP375T, inova semiconductor) states these rules:

```
-constant distance between the diff. traces
-pairs equal in length to avoid skew
-designed for 100 ohm impedance
-no vias, stay on top layer
-100nF 0402 or 0603 caps, ac-coupled signals
```

[image]

The QFP 100 IC is located on the left side. In between the diff traces theres a decoupling cap in 0603. The traces go to the right side, and just before they enter the connector there's an esd protection diode array with the ground tap in the middle (according to the manufacturer#s suggestion). After this diode array, the traces continue at 0.2 width and 0.3mm distance.
The lengths are (top to bottom): 34.06mm, 34.00mm (that's the transmitter pair), 30.62mm, 30.97mm (receiving pair).

The transmitting pair is running at max 3Gbit/s, although I slowed it down to 1GBit/s for the sake of debugging and testing, receiving is done at 62MBit/s.

I got the pcb and assembled the parts by hand. I programmed the microcontroller to interface with the INAP375, and set up a configuration which I know is working on a development board from inova.

But, I do not get a link between the transmitter and the display. ANd now I am lost, where to search for the error. My main question is:

Is it possible that the impedance mismatch is responsible for the failure, or the almost non-existing skew?

The config I programmed into the INAP375 works perfectly on said development board. Transfering it to my own pcb results in instant connection loss, which makes it very hard to search for an issue within the configuration. But I somehow doubt that a length skew with this little difference has an impact on the performance. Which leaaes the impedance mismatch, but I wonder how to improve the design. I could go back to 0.3mm after the esd diodes, but does it really affect the transmission by this much? Apart from that, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: For future reference: The rf-part was perfectly fine, even the width changed. It was a hidden difference in their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Start with nice earth grounded end 0V points high quality cable, CM chokes for cable,  to avoid SMPS CM issues getting into differential signals.

Then read about group delay distortion from abrupt changes in trace thickness, skew and lack of impedance controlled FR4 electrical test and how eye patterns get closed.

https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-319-14346-0_41

I have a nicely designed HDMI port on a good  8core i8 ASUS tower that gets sparklies on video porttions to a 1080p big screen until I put my finger over the CM choke. So much for automated connection Group Delay equalization  routine....routine or left out??  BUt if I get a real high quality shielded HDMI short cable its clean. 3 others various noise lefts. Any cable kinks it get permanently worse.  This is also running at similar speeds to your test.

The feedthru caps I think should be the ideal low ESL X2Y types only.